# Rating music by time offset location

Tags: linux, media-player, rating

I’m looking for something like a music player ([MPD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon) client preferred) - or even a separate rating software, that allows me to mark positions in a track that I like.

Just assigning one to five stars or so to an MP3 file plus time offset in it would help.

Nice extras would be to mark ranges instead of points, and to assign names or annotations to the rated points.

I think the handling of existing points would be similar to web bookmarks.